# 'app-user-component' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am working on my ionic 5 work and am having this error that says: ['app-user-component' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-user-component' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-user-component' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.] in my location html page. The function was working previously but this error suddenly appeared. Any advice please help. Thank you.

location page.html

```
<ion-row>
        <ion-col size-sm="6" offset-sm="3">
          <app-user-component (locationPick)="onLocationPicked($event)"></app-user-component>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
```

location page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, ReactiveFormsModule, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { PlaceLocation } from '../location/location.model';
import { LocationService } from '../services/location.service';

interface userData {
  Temperature: number;
  Location: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-location',
  templateUrl: './location.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./location.page.scss'],
})
export class LocationPage implements OnInit {
  temperature: number;
  location: string;
  mapLocation: string;

  form: FormGroup;
  userData: userData;

  constructor(
    public fb: FormBuilder,
    public reactiveForm: ReactiveFormsModule,
    private locationService: LocationService,
  ) {
    this.userData = {} as userData;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      temperature: new FormControl(null, {
        updateOn: 'blur',
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.min(30.0)]
      }),
      mapLocation: new FormControl(null, { validators: [Validators.required] })
    });
  }

  onLocationPicked(mapLocation: PlaceLocation) {
    this.form.patchValue({ mapLocation: mapLocation });
  }

  onCreateUser() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
    this.locationService.create_user(this.form.value).then(resp => {
      this.form.reset();
    })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    this.form.reset();
  }

}
```

user component.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-component',
  templateUrl: './user-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-component.component.scss'],
})
```

Comment: Have you imported `UserComponent` in your module?

Comment: yes i have, but the error is still there

Comment: This might be a dumb suggestion - but sometimes when I get the same error (and have hooked everything up correctly) I need to restart my `ng serve`.

Comment: Injecting `ReactiveFormsModule` into your component is definitely wrong. Probably not related but I'm surprised that doesn't fail with a missing provider error